# Can suspensions be separated by centrifuge or by separatory funnel?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

I want to know if we could separate suspensions whose particle sizes are more than $\pu{100 nm}$ like mud by a normal centrifuge?

Could we use a separatory funnel for these situations?

Comment: I mean, filtering might work. What is the range of sizes of particles?

Comment: Also, suspensions eventually settle

Comment: @JavaScriptCoder After watching my colleague separate some iron nanoparticles I can tell you that ‘eventually’ can mean an incredibly long timeframe …

Comment: @Jan yes, but wouldn’t mud be different than iron nanoparticles?

Comment: @JavaScriptCoder Sure, but your ‘all’-implying sentence needed a partial rebuttal ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you are indeed dealing with a proper suspension (not a colloid and not a solution) then centrifugation should always work to separate the components. It may be that you need a very high rotation speed or a long time, but you will manage to get the solid particles to the bottom of the tube and the clear liquid above.

A separatory funnel is a bad idea for a number of reasons. For one, you don’t know how long it will take for the components to separate. For two, you will probably have difficulties removing the solid portions; they might clog the opening or they might attach together not intending to go through at all. Finally, you will always get some liquid together with the solid fraction in a separatory funnel while you should arrive at a much better dryness with centrifugation.